# Converting PanelMatch Estimates to Marginal Effects in Non-Linear Outcome Models

Tags: panel-data, causality, count-data, matching, marginal-effect

I am interested in using the [{PanelMatch}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PanelMatch/PanelMatch.pdf) package for a project that I am working on where the conventional matching/weighting framework is expanded to account for the complexities of the panel data setting.

Both within the reference manual and their associated [paper](https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/tscs.pdf), the authors rely on research questions with a continuous outcome as demonstrations of their method. However, my research project has a count outcome. I've emailed one of the authors and got the following comment, "PanelMatch can be used for any outcome, not just a continuous one. If it's a binary outcome, for example, you have to interpret it on the probability scale."

Does anyone know how one would go about converting estimates from PanelMatch into a marginal effect for a limited dependent variable (in my case, a count outcome)?

Comment: If you find an approach to this, would be great to know.